# What is best?Submit form on large html table or jquery?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I have this project in Laravel and I have this list of emails in a html table ,each row has a checkbox, if I check X checkboxes I want to send a email to all of them.

Not worried about the email procedure but it will be in a php file, what I dont know is how to do the logic, should I encapsulate all of the table in a form with the action going to the php file or should I control this with a jquery ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the checkbox with a form :

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mailadre@gmail.com">
  <input type="checkbox" name="otheradre@yahoo.fr">
   ....
  <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
</from>
```

Only the checked checkboxes will be send by the browser and receive by php. In fact on the php side, on script.php $_POST will be an array containing the checked mail adresses :)

---

### EDIT :

If you don't want to reload the page and get acualized data you will have to use javascript with ajax calls.

You have to include a js script in your html that fetch a php page every x seconds to get the actual amount of orders and replace the value in the browser. This php page job will be only to display this number.

Ajax calls are executed after the browser get the page from the server, they are executed by the browser. As soon as PHP server send the page, it care no more, the only way to interact with it is by the client browser, in this exemple with an Ajax call to an url on the server that will repond only with the total amount of order. So in background of the browser it will require actualized datas to the PHP server.

---

To be honest JSON is probably the way you should go to be able to send total amount of order + all kind of other actualized infos to include in your page.

It would give you for exemple something like that `{totalOrder = 142, lastConnection = "Jean-Philippe", LastOrderDate= "2020-11-18"}` if you encode this array on the PHP server side:

```
$result = [ "totalOrder " => 142, 
            "lastConnection " => "Jean-Philippe", 
            "LastOrderDate"=> "2020-11-18"];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Then you can easily replace content in your HTML page in javascript with this JSON response from your PHP server.

See detailed exemple here :https://makitweb.com/return-json-response-ajax-using-jquery-php/

---

Have a nice day.

Comment: Perfect,thanks! What if I did not want to leave page? It would be better to use jquery right? Or vueja

Comment: @dreid, Here it is, I edited my response with the Ajax way without reloading to do it. Full exemple in the link I posted. Enjoy :)